# Stop function when event happens

Tags: java, algorithm

For the sake of simplicity, let's say I have a function containing 10 lines of code, each line taking 1 second to be executed. Now the code in this function should run only under one condition, and if this condition becomes unverified during the execution of the code (e.g. between line 5 and line 6), the function should stop immediately.

How can I achieve this behavior withtout placing a `if(condition)return;`   statement before each line ?

This is how I imagined it :

```
private void function(){
    eventsManager.register(new OnConditionChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onConditionUnverified() {
            //something like function.exit()
        }
    });

    line 1;
    line 2;
     ...
    line 5;
    //onConditionUnverified is triggered from somewhere
    //the next lines should not be executed
     ...
    line 10;
}
```

Comment: I don't think there's a way to (reasonably) do this.  Even `Thread.interrupt()` requires polling.

Comment: Why not to go from the other side? Run this method as separate thread and if stopCondition occurs, kill worker thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can throw a RuntimeException then the execution of function() will be interrupt.

Your willingness is try to control your code flow using such as eventsManager.check(...),  every code-flow-path-change should be managed by you code. Throw a exception and use try-catch block to control the code flow path is a good way if you don't mind some loss of performance :)